# nodemailer xoauth2 connect timed out error

Tags: gmail, nodemailer

I am currently trying to get nodemailer to work locally but I keep running into a connection timed out error. I have tried multiple other ways, or even trying other snippets of code but it hasn't been working for me.

```
app.post('/contact/send', (req,res)=>{

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
        user: 'mail@gmail.com',
        clientId: 'clientID',
        clientSecret:'itsasecret',
        refreshToken:'refresh',
        accessToken:'access token'
      })
    },
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Website Contact" <mail@gmail.com>',
    to: 'mail@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Website Inquiry',
    text: 'Name: ' + req.body.name + 'Email: ' + req.body.email + 'Message: '+req.body.text,
    html: '<p>You have a submission with the following details: </p><ul><li>Name: '
    + req.body.name + '</li><li>Email: '
    + req.body.email + "</li><li>Message: "
    + req.body.message + "</li></ul>"
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      console.log('Message sent');
      res.render('/contact');
     }
  })

})
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.0.37:587
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.217.0.37',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

any help or guidance please?